# The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

My program throws this exception online,I know the reason why it is wrong.
My question is how do I find the wrong place,The Java cannot catch the location of this exception.
  How do I get additional information about this exception,For example, the API for this error requested address.

The error message is as follows:

```
2019-01-18  07:49:23.076 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8081-exec-96] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:484)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Seems like there are debug statements in that class https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11InputBuffer.java#L386 . You should be able to see what's wrong when you enable debug logger with name `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer`

Comment: Since it is online, the debug mode is not turned on.

Answer (score 27):

If you use an upper version of Tomcat 8.5 it throws this exception if the URL path contains '[' and ']'. For older versions, it works.

Comment: Yes, this error occurs because the parameters in the path have special characters.so,we should 'encodeURL' your parameters before passing them.or   replace the GET with POST methods.

Comment: Ya, in my case, I was missing encodeURIComponent(). I used JSON.Stringify() on my object, but that was not sufficient. When I saw this, I immediately had a D'oh moment.

Answer (score 15):

The workaround would be adding below attributes to http connector port in tomcat `server.xml` file

```
relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^\`"<>"
```

Comment: should be `relaxedQueryChars='[]|{}^\`"<>'`

Comment: the angle brackets are not allowed in the version 9.x.x

Comment: I added the relaxedPathChars and relaxedQueryChars to my server.xml but I'm still getting same error at Internet Explorer. My Tomcat version is 9.0.58

Comment: My tomcat complains about illegal characters in the answer and the comment above. Consider using `relaxedPathChars="[]|"` and `relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"` if you're having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

The error message says "Invalid character found in the request target". This means the HTTP client sent a request for a resource that had an invalid characters in it. The server can not parse the request because the request did not adhere to the HTTP protocol specifications.

This is a client problem. Fix the client.

If it is a public server, maybe someone is trying to break in by sending malformed requests (it's common).

Comment: The problem is an exception thrown by the online server，I did not have this problem in the local test

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error when sending location of a file in a AJAX GET request.

Since the location had characters which are not recognized. I.e. "C:///" etc, the error was thrown.

The use of `encodeURIComponent` helped me fix the issue since it encodes the component.

When you pass the location make sure you add those inside "`encodeURIComponent`" method. In my case:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'removeFile?removeFilePath=' + encodeURIComponent("C:///YO/Ed/PO/")
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
```

Answer (score 2):

Used Tomcat v8.5, below update in server.xml works for me since '<>' is not allowed

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^`'"/>
```

Comment: Yes this worked for me in Tomcat 8.5

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring Boot application, just add to properties file:

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=|,{,},[,],^
```

if you use application.yaml just add following config

```
server:
  tomcat:
    relaxed-query-chars: '|,{,},[,],^'
```